# Value not passed passed to secondviewcontroller when the segue is triggered using table view cells of the firstviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

Ok so what do I want to achieve: I have a table view controller and a normal view controller.
In the table view controller there a bunch of values from an array.

What I want: when the user selects a cell with the value of a particular array I want the view controller to display detailinfo about that cell.

For some reason dragging the segue in the storyboard doesn't really work, I can drag it but it doesn't push the screen of the second viewcontroller when I select a cell.

This is the code I have to solve this + I thought about adding an indicator of which cell was tapped. But when the second view controller is loaded the pickedRow value = 0 again.

This is the code for the FirstViewController.m

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
    secondView.pickedRow = indexPath.row;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"artiestenDetailSegue" sender: self];
}
```

In the viewDidLoad of SecondViewController I have this, this just always returns 0:

```
    if (pickedRow == 1) {
        detailLabel.text = @"eerste";
}
```

Everything is imported correctly and no errors. What could the issue be?

Comment: read more about storyboards from apples documentation.. this is not how it works

Comment: I have checked so many things, if you now what line of code I am missing or doing wrong please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`SecondViewController *secondView = [segue destinationViewController];
    secondView.pickedRow = indexPath.row;`

Comment: I guess you mean to put this in prepareforsegue because otherwise a segue is not declared? Well then indexpath.row doesn't work.
I am really just a starter.